# Drawing Retina resolution on CGDisplayGetDrawingContext

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-graphics, quartz-core

I have a situation were I'm trying to draw an image into a display's `CGContext` retrieved using `CGDisplayGetDrawingContext`. Despite having the image at the correct high resolution, using `CGContextDrawImage` to draw the image onto the context results in a pixilated image. I've also tried scaling down the image in a bitmap context (using `CGBitmapContextCreate`) then drawing that one onto the display's context, however that also results in a pixilated image (I thought it may retain the DIP, was a long shot). Any idea how to fix this?.

Comment: Any reason why you are not using CALayer-backed fullscreen mode? I'd suggest that. Could be that this bug is because of Apple not supporting properly this method on HiDPI displays. Then again, I am not really familiar with this side of macOS development.

Comment: @LeoNatan I guess you're right. I've tried everything to get the image to properly display on retina displays but no luck, so yeah I think I'll follow your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: If you are a paid developer, another option is to open a development support ticket with Apple. Each account has two of those a year (you can purchase more). But I think what I suggested is better, not only for code simplicity, but also from users' UX standpoint.